# whats the minimum PC spec i should be looking at for doing video editing

Tags: upgrade, video-editing

i am in the market for a new PC and i wanted to see what the minimun spec i should be looking at to be able to run

- Adobe Flash Professional
- Adobe Premiere Pro or other Video Editing software

i can obviously see the min specs on their website but i find that sometimes is not very reliable to really understand what i should be looking at.

What in particular specs (memory, hard disk, graphics card, etc) should i be focusing on to run this type of software effectively . . .

Comment: Why? Just match the System Requirements of the software with the machine you're going to buy, and I can promise you they're 100% fulfilled. For multimedia editing, invest in RAM and a fast hard disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with slhck as far as look at the system requirements, but virtually anything you buy today will exceed that. Definitely exceed those numbers by a fair amount since those are usually bare minimums. Get as much RAM as you can, and go with a 64-bit OS. Hard disk space is cheap, so go with plenty (at least 1TB) since video takes up a lot of space.

Comment: Just like to say that one of the most important notes from slhcks' comment was a "fast" hard drive - RAID 1 is something to look at, my video editing hard drives are set up in RAID10 for this reason.

Comment: To be honest he can also do that, but I most bare drives are pretty fast, so I did not really bother to mention it.

Comment: You can also get drives with firmware specifically for video editing/streaming than minimise latency and enhance contiguous throughout

Answer (score 0):

It has to be 64 bit OS as  Premiere Pro requires so.

minimum recommendations

RAM: 2 -4 GB 
HDD: 320-500 GB 
Processor: i5

Good Recommendations

RAM: 8-16 GB. 16 GB is max 
HDD: 1 - 2 TB 
Processor: Intel i7

thanks!